# SPARQL CONTRUCT ordered list with ORDER BY and GROUP BY

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

Dear RDF/SPARQL community,

my goal is to construct an ordered list grouped by products and ordered by time by the means of SPARQL to show the track of a product. I am working with GraphDB, "scmon" is my custom ontology. And here are the details:

I have stored RDF data that hold the timestamps (`scmon:atTime`) and positions (`scmon:atLocation`) of products. In Turtle syntax it looks like this:

```
@base <http://example/base/testtracks> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix scmon: <http://www.semanticweb.org/sildop/ontologies/2020/scmon#> .

<tracks5> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-10T14:48:59Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <5>;
  scmon:positionOf <product1> .

<tracks6> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-12T13:37:19Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <5002>;
  scmon:positionOf <product1> .

<tracks7> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-13T19:46:00Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <2>;
  scmon:positionOf <product1> .

<tracks17> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-10T14:48:59Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <4953>;
  scmon:positionOf <product2> .

<tracks18> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-12T13:37:19Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <4953004195>;
  scmon:positionOf <product2> .

<tracks19> a scmon:NetPosition;
  scmon:atTime "2018-12-13T19:46:00Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp;
  scmon:atLocation <4176>;
  scmon:positionOf <product2> .
```

As you may see, every `track` entry is assigned to a `product` via the `scmon:positionOf` relation.

My goal is now to construct an **ordered list grouped by products and ordered by time** by the means of SPARQL to show the track of a product in a form similar to:

```
<product1> scmon:hasPosSequence <track5>
  <track5> scmon:nextPosition <track6>
  <track6> scmon:nextPosition <track7>
  <track7> scmon:nextPosition NULL
<product2> ...
```

This approach was inspired by the W3C example Pattern 2 for n-ary relations (https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/#pattern2) which looks like this: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/flight_example.jpg

Also my custom ontology with the prefix `scmon` has adapted the suggested structure (with similar named classes and relations) that looks like this https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/flight_classes.jpg

I was able to construct the first relation/line for `<scmon:hasPosSequence>` that points from the product  `?product` to the first position `?netPos` that is found by `(min(?time))`...

```
PREFIX scmon: <http://www.semanticweb.org/sildop/ontologies/2020/scmon#>
CONSTRUCT {?product scmon:hasPosSequence ?netPos}
where {
    {
    ?product ^scmon:positionOf ?netPos .
    ?netPos scmon:atTime ?startTime .
    }
    {
                select ?product (min(?time) as ?startTime)
                where {
                    ?netPos scmon:positionOf ?product .
                    ?netPos scmon:atTime ?time .
                } group by ?product 
            }
        }
```

...but how could I go on from there? I have tried some SPARQL SELECT queries to test if I may select the information that is necessary to construct the `scmon:nextPosition` relation, but with no success.

Is it possible to construct this pattern? Or do I have to change my initial RDF data model somehow?

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```sql
PREFIX scmon: <http://www.semanticweb.org/sildop/ontologies/2020/scmon#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?product scmon:hasPosSequence ?track0 .
  ?track1 scmon:nextPosition ?track3
} WHERE {
  
  ?track1 scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time1 .
    
  OPTIONAL {
    ?track2 scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time2 .
    FILTER (?time2 > ?time1)
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?track_ scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time_
      FILTER (?time_ > ?time1 && ?time_ < ?time2)
    }
  }
  BIND (COALESCE(?track2, scmon:NULL, ?track2) AS ?track3)
    
  ?track0 scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time0 .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?track_ scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time_
    FILTER (?time_ < ?time0)
    }
}
```

By the way, if you need to number positions, try the following:

```
SELECT ?product ?track (COUNT(?track_) AS ?position) {
  ?track scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time .
  ?track_ scmon:positionOf ?product ;  scmon:atTime ?time_
  FILTER (?time >= ?time_)                         
} GROUP BY ?product ?track ORDER BY ?product ?position
```

As for `NULL`s in RDF, see [this discussion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-lod/2013Jun/thread.html#msg7). If you really want them to be represented explicitely, you could use `rdf:List`s which end with `rdf:nil`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the hint on `Null` in RDF! I think I do not need them explicitely: My ontology stores the information that a `track` with `:nextPosition max 0` cardinality is classified as a `FinalTrack`. And I thought `Null` would be the equivalent to `max 0` cardinality that tells the inference machine to infer that a `track` is a `FinalTrack`... Now I know that was an incorrect assumption on my part. Would that be a case for using SHACL validation to test wheter the cardinality is adhered to?

Comment: @SilviD, `max 0` is problematic due to open world assumption; you could use SHACL rules, if GraphDB supports them: https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks. For anyone who encounters the same issue: The user documentation of GraphDB (9.5) says that is supports SHACL Validation [here](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/shacl-validation.html)

Comment: GDB 10.3 doesn't support SHACL Advanced https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/shacl-validation.html but 10.4 will support it